# ftp server in C

Tags: c, ftp

I have to develop 1 FTP (simple) server in C.
What do i mean with *simple*??
I mean that FTP server has to support:

1. authentication (USER, PASS, PORT)
2. change directory (CD)
3. file listing (LIST)
4. file retrive (RETR)

I have just developed as "split part" the numbers 1-2-3-4 and i have to merge them into *main.c*. So no problem with them.
What i don't understand is how to "receive" communications from the client.
I mean how can implement what the client wants (USER, PASS, CD, LIST, RETR)?
I've read the rfc959 but i have not totally understood the communication between client and sever.
Summary:

1. client connect to server (so into the server this part is the socket "accept(..)"), rigth?
   1a server send to client "you are connected" right?
2. client send to server user,password (file 1, auth.c but i don't know how to read when client send to the server the user and password request)
3. after successful login the server send file list (part 3, list.c, no problem)
4. the client send to the server the file it wants to download or the changedir command (again, how to read this info from client's request?)

i hope you have understand :)

**EDIT:** i'm on GNU/Linux

Comment: I recommend you start even simpler, by reading network tutorials until you know what sockets are and how they work, how you create simple clients, simple servers, the difference between blocking and non-blocking sockets, servers that can handle multiple connections (in basically that order). Then you can start looking into making a FTP server.

Comment: Of course, besides the above network related stuff, you also need some basic understanding of things like strings and string parsing, file handling, and lists.

Comment: i've developed a small client and server(also with fork) but they works not like and ftp client and server. In fact my program use are: 1) client connect to server 2) client send "file list" 3) server send the result 4) client send file name 5) server send file...so not properly like an ftp xD

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is more about how to parse the commands the client send, is that correct? I think you should split this overly general questions into more specific questions, each one describing a single problem you have.

Comment: Read Stevens' books regarding networking programming, and for gods sake, avoid Beej's guide like it was radioactive.

Comment: So Beej's guide is not good? Or are you jocking?? xD however, i'll buy the Steven's books, thanks  :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, you're right! So i have to close this question and open another one with **less** things into it, right? :)

Comment: Yes, that's right. Keep the questions short and concise, and preferable only one problem per question. As for your problem, you should check out [`strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is little confusing, I am trying to answer it. Take command line parameters like "Username Password" and pass these `argv[]` through `send` to Server and receive using `recv` at Server end. For better understanding, refer the link [Client.cpp](http://www.mtholyoke.edu/~xuansun/csamples/ftp/client_cpp.html)

Hope this solves your confusion.

Comment: Do remember to upvote and accept the solution if it helps you :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Berkeley sockets API (your mentioning `accept()` implies that you are), you typically use `recv()` to read data from a socket. You need to read from the socket the client is connecting to, then inspect what you got to determine if it's a valid command that you can handle.

Comment: oh sorry :) yes i'm developing on GNU/Linux :)

Comment: but what i cannot understand is "what the client send"? It sends "USER username PASS pasw" or "Hello USER selected is username" or other??

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a code to learn the workings of ftp with sockets and found filework on google code and the code clear and simple.
URL: http://code.google.com/p/ifilework